# `scipy.optimize.root` faster root finding

Tags: python, performance, scipy, mathematical-optimization, root-finding

I use `scipy.optimize.root` with the `hybr` method (best one ?) to find the root of a numeric function

I print the residual at each iteration

`delta d 117.960112417
delta d 117.960112417 
delta d 117.960112417
delta d 117.960048733 
delta d 117.960112427
delta d 117.960112121
delta d 1.46141491664
delta d 0.0322651167588
delta d 0.000363688881595
delta d 4.05494689256e-08`

How can I accelerate the root finding, by increasing the size of the step, especially between the firsts iterations ?
I don't know how exactly work the algorithm, but it looks strange that the 3 first results are the same, and 3 nexts are quite identical too.

[Reading the doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.root-hybr.html#optimize-root-hybr), I've tried to modify the `eps` factor, without sucess

EDIT : @sasha, here is a very basic function to illustrate the issue

```
def f(X1,X2):
    print ' X1 , diff , norm ' , X1 , X2 - X1 , np.linalg.norm(X2 - X1)
    return X2 - X1

Xa = np.array([1000,1000,1000,1000])
Xb = np.array([2000,2000,2000,2000])

SOL = scipy.optimize.root(f,Xa,(Xb,))
```

The result will be the following
We have the 3 identical iterations at the beginning, whatever the length of X

```
 X1 , diff , norm  [1000 1000 1000 1000] [1000 1000 1000 1000] 2000.0
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.] [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.] 2000.0
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.] [ 1000.  1000.  1000.  1000.] 2000.0
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 1000.0000149  1000.         1000.         1000.       ] [  999.9999851  1000.         1000.         1000.       ] 1999.99999255
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 1000.         1000.0000149  1000.         1000.       ] [ 1000.          999.9999851  1000.         1000.       ] 1999.99999255
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 1000.         1000.         1000.0000149  1000.       ] [ 1000.         1000.          999.9999851  1000.       ] 1999.99999255
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 1000.         1000.         1000.         1000.0000149] [ 1000.         1000.         1000.          999.9999851] 1999.99999255
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 2000.  2000.  2000.  2000.] [-0. -0. -0. -0.] 4.36239133705e-09
 X1 , diff , norm  [ 2000.  2000.  2000.  2000.] [ 0.  0.  0.  0.] 0.0
```

Comment: Without knowing details about your function / data, this can't be answered satisfactorily.

Comment: What happens if you provide gradients?

Answer (score 5):

First, I think you are confusing iterations with calls to your function, which are not quite exactly the same. Because you have not provided the solver with a Jacobean function, it must estimate the Jacobean (or perhaps just some part of it) itself. The Jacobean is basically the multidimensional equivalent of the derivative. It indicates how the output of the objective function changes as you slightly vary the inputs.

Most numerical solvers estimate Jacobeans numerically by evaluating the objective function at some point very close to the current guess and checking to see how much the output changes by. My guess is that the first few calls you see are to evaluate the objective function, and then estimate the Jacobean. The first call where you see any actual change happens after it has estimated the Jacobean and then used it to compute a next guess at the root.

If you wish to check this for yourself, try giving the solver a callback function. It will call this function on every iteration and you can look to see where it is at each iteration. I think you will find that it converges in only a few iterations, but calls the function multiple times per iteration.

Of course, you can avoid all this work by providing the solver with a Jacobean function it can call to evaluate the Jacobean at a point. If you do this, it will not need to make multiple calls to estimate it.

The documentation has information on how to add callbacks and provide a Jacobean function. If needed, I can add an example.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html

Comment: OK, so the first calls are for the Jacobian estimation
It looks like a hard work to provide a externally calculated, so I will let scipy doing the work ;)

Comment: @Covich The alternative is to us scipy to give you the Jacobian.